# Jquery plugin in emberjs template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, ember.js

Hi im trying to make a simple feed reader using ember.js and feedek. But so far when I try to place the code for the feed, it not working.

Jquery code for feedek (inside the index template in a script tag):

```
$('#divRss').FeedEk({
    FeedUrl: 'http://vikinglogue.com/feed/',
    MaxCount: 100
});
```

Html Code for template:

```
<script data-template-name="index" type="text/x-handlebars">
    <article style="background-color:#fff;" id="divRss"></article>
</script>
```

When I run this code in the browser, nothing in the template shows up and I'm not getting any errors. I think the issue is caused by not linking feedek in the template but when I tried it, nothing happened. Thanks, any help is appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a jQuery plugin in an Ember app, it's usually best to wrap it in a [component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/):

```
App.FeedEkComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'article',

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().FeedEk({
      FeedUrl: 'http://vikinglogue.com/feed/',
      MaxCount: 100
    });
  }
});
```

Then in one of your Handlebars templates,

```
<p>Your feed:</p>
{{feed-ek}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just have one quick question: do I need the {{feed-ek}} because I already have a {{output}} in the main template. How can I just show the feed in there?

Answer (score 1):

I would add to Sam's excellent answer as follows:

1. Make the component reusable by passing in the url as a property
2. Don't override didInsertElement hook, instead specify that the function should run on 'didInsertElement' event (see [here](http://fishtank.eviltrout.com/t/wrapping-a-jquery-plugin-in-a-ember-js-component-screencast/222/6))

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/boguwagisi/1/edit?html,js,output